# Мессенджер. многопоточная реализация или асинхронная?

Tags: c++, асинхронность, boost.asio

Пишу мессенджер(сервер и клиенты). От клиента требуется отправлять сообщения и параллельно их принимать(+ уметь переходить в другой чат, выходить из него и тд). Есть ли смысл реализовывать клиента асинхронно или лучше просто закинуть в 2 потока и всё?